# Is it possible to remove _typeTag from Serilog's output?

Tags: c#, serilog

I'm using Serilog to write structured log data to Elasticsearch via Logstash. When writing an object in a log message like so

```
Log.Information("This is the {@object}", new {Prop = "example"})
```

An additional property, _typeTag is included in the JSON that is output. Is it possible to exclude this property?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to specify a custom `ITextFormatter` when logging to Elasticsearch with Serilog. The property in `ElasticsearchSinkOptions` is:

```
public ITextFormatter CustomFormatter { get; set; }
```

You might need to do some work to get a custom formatter configured the way you want - subclassing Serilog's `JsonFormatter`, or the `ElasticsearchJsonFormatter` that's provided with the sink, or forking to create your own, might work.

Comment: I'm not logging directly to elasticsearch, only to a file on the local system, then using logstash to ship the logs.

Comment: Is the file being written in JSON format? If so, you can pass the custom `ITextFormatter` to the file sink configuration in the same way. HTH! :-)